# Sublime Text 3 - Custom Command - Adding Text to element

Tags: command, sublimetext3

I'd like to create a custom keybinding on ST3 so that whenever I highlight an element or my cursos is next to it, it surrounds it with a predefined text.

Something that would look like that

```
{
"keys": ["ctrl+shift+m"], "command": "insert_snippet"
,"args": {"contents": "text before", "text after"}
}
```

So that: file.js

becomes: text before file.js text after

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Are the before and after texts always the same?

Comment: Yes it would be used to turn something like:

file.css into <link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css">

Comment: I'm sorry, the solution of my answer only works when the text is selected, but not when its highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text that should be inserted after and before the selection is always the same you can use the **$SELECTION variable**:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+m"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "BEFORE_TEXT ${SELECTION} AFTER_TEXT"} }
```

Comment: Thank you sergioFC, your solution is fine, I managed to tweak it to my preferences with some documentation :)